# Image does not load when web was hosted but gif does when using source from the internet

Tags: html, image, src

When the source is local storage it is fine, but not when the source is from internet.

This img works when involves a gif.

```
<img width="300" height="200" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/f4a65498-5cd1-434f-8981-dd95d972fe6e/scale-to-width/755" alt="Brook laughing at Sanji after meeting Duval"/>
```

but it does not load when involves a picture.

```
<img width="300" height="500" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/onepiece/images/6/6d/Monkey_D._Luffy_Anime_Post_Timeskip_Infobox.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/239?cb=20200429191518/400" alt="Luffy appearance after time-skip" />
```

The picture does load when I open html locally on chrome, but does not when previewed on VS Code and when hosted to the web.

Comment: it seems that the second image is protected by the server from external usage and linking!

Comment: oh, that could be it, I'll try using another image and update

Comment: It did work when I tried another source. thanks!

Comment: did you upload these images to static.wikia.nocookie.net yourself? 
the only reason is cross site linking protection. because the image loads successfully when directly opened.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering persistent issues with an image hosted on an external website, and you have the option to do so, downloading the image and hosting it locally on your server or within your project can be a good solution. Here's how you can do it:

Download the Image:

Visit the website where the image is hosted.
Right-click on the image you want to use.
Select "Save image as..." or a similar option to download the image to your computer.
Store the Image Locally:

Place the downloaded image in a directory within your project's folder structure. Create a new directory if needed, such as "images" or "assets."
Update the HTML Code:

Update the src attribute of the  tag to point to the local path of the image you downloaded. For example:

```
<img width="300" height="500" src="images/your-downloaded-image.png" alt="Image Description">
```

Comment: This reads like a ChatGPT answer

Comment: The question is about image from web, @aimanakashah sad that it works fine with local images